# How to get a Value from NodeList?

Tags: javascript, console, nodelist

I use document.getElementsByName("phone") to get this NodeList (2).
How can i get the value from a special key from List 0?
Can i extend the document.getElementsByName to get the value for example for [0].dafaultValue ?

[NodeList example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pX195.png)

Comment: `theNodeList[0].dafaultValue` will get you the value for `defaultValue` for the first item. If that's what you need, then you can already do it. If you tried it and it doesn't work, then what is the problem you encountered?

Comment: I dont know how to write this in the getElementsByName. i tried this: document.getElementsByName("phone" [0].defaulValue), but it doenst work. How to do it right?

Answer (score 0):

One way to access the items returned from `getElementsByNodeName` is from [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp):

```js
const collection = document.getElementsByName("phone");
for (let i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
  let valueYouAreInterestedIn = collection[i].specialKeyYouWant;
  // Use the value below :)
}
```

Please comment if there is anything else you need help with!